# Tax Import Magento - get success message but taxes not showing

Tags: magento

I'm importing a csv file for all California USA postcodes as we only need to charge sales tax to California addresses. If I set the tax rates up per postcode manually this is fine, but when i attempt to import through the csv, i receive a success message "the tax rate has been imported" but the tax rates are nowhere to be seen within the admin.
Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Here is a csv of just a couple of lines I'm trying as a test before populating with all postcodes https://www.dropbox.com/s/5h1wmm3jfdmwjse/tax_rates-3.csv

and screenshot:

Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A programming site. Your question isn't a programming related question. You should post your question on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, make sure you don't have trailing spaces in your csv.

This file wil work:
https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/03/quick-tip-setup-eu-tax-rates-in-magento-quickly/